# Speeding up the Object Synchronization when rendering

Tags: rendering

When I have large scenes with lots of geometry building the BVH and "synchronizing" the objects. Is there a way to speed it up?
I am using Blender 2.77.

Comment: BVH Catching has been [removed](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Cycles) in Blender 2.77.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Btw, you misspelled "caching" ;-)

Comment: Ok it [appears](http://adaptivesamples.com/2015/10/25/cache-bvh-is-no-more/) I didn't check that since. I don't think [general tips](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/performance.html) can help to increase synchronizing objects but probably they could save some render times for you instead.